# Is there a specific name for the activity of blowing the bellows?

Tags: single-word-requests, archaicisms

In a few European languages, there are words derived from latin *calcare* - literally to tread, in these words it means to blow bellows, for example in church organs; in Polish it's *kalikować* - a nearly-forgotten word by now, along with *Kalikant*, which was the name of the occupation - the person performing the work.

Is there a counterpart to that word in English, or did English always use plain "blowing the bellows"?

Comment: For blacksmiths I've always seen this phrased as "working the bellows".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this historic article mentioning organ pumpers and the "organ-pumping art":

http://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1817&dat=19380415&id=s-4-AAAAIBAJ&sjid=IE0MAAAAIBAJ&pg=4307,4907611

There are lots of similar results for 'organ pumper' in Google.

Answer (score 6):

Pump organs depended on someone (or something) to *[pump](http://www.pumporganrestorations.com/no_more_foot_pumping.htm)* the bellows.

Comment: According to [Google Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blow+the+bellows%2Cpump+the+bellows%2Cwork+the+bellows%2C+tread+the+bellows&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=), bellows are *blown, pumped,* or *worked,* with roughly equal frequency. I don't know any other verbs for this. (Ngrams confirms that they are generally not trodden.)

Comment: @PeterShor For _organ_ bellows? Never heard of those being _worked_. And those that were _blown_ had a motor doing the work. (I grew up around choirs, and my share of pipe organs of varying age and grandeur.)

Comment: I would have said *pump* as well. But if you believe the Ngram, then before around 1900, bellows weren't pumped—they were either worked or blown. There were certainly church organs before then, so I wouldn't be surprised if some regions of the world are still using *work* or *blow* instead of *pump*. I can find both words used for pipe organs in Google books, although *blow* seems more common.

Comment: Thing is "kalikować" isn't connected with any subject! You don't say "kalikować *miechy*" any more than you say "to spell letters" or "to pinpoint a pin" - the bellows are inherently implied and always omitted. You could at most distinguish: at church or at the smithy.

Comment: Then please clarify what you are asking for. Are you in fact asking for the name of the person pumping the bellows? Most were pumped by the organist's feet. The larger ones were pumped by the assistant or understudy.

Comment: @Gnawme: I'm asking if there exists in English a single word that means "pumping bellows" (the same way as "fishing" means "catching fish"). If there is no such word in English, such answer will be perfectly acceptable too.

Answer (score 1):

Calcant - one who pumps the bellows while the organist plays